# using TOR (served by nginx) wit ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, tor

I've set up a hidden service via [hidden service with nginx](https://www.thecthulhu.com/setting-up-a-hidden-service-with-nginx/)
which works quite good though.
No i want to secure that connection by using a self signed cert, which i've already created.

This is my hidden service vhost file:

```
server {
server_name myHASH.onion;
listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
root /var/www/;
client_max_body_size 99M;
index index.html index.php;
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd;
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;

    }  }
```

which works for me, the hidden service is online and active.
Now i want to add SSL certificates, saldy i don't have an idea on how to do that as the connection 'comes' from 'within'.

So, what do i have to add into my hidden service vhost file in order to get ssl support?

Thanks in advance!
Mark

Answer (score 2):

You don’t really need SSL/TLS in an onion address (ie. https) since it’s a complete encrypted tunnel + PFS (perfect forward secrecy), but it does not hurt having extra layers in that onion!

Although it is true that extra layers are good beware that usually redirecting to SSL/TLS will mean that the certificate will not validate (because the hostname will be *.onion, instead of the certificate that you have for your public service). If you can get a .onion certificate, that works!